# Beginner Python surface calculation of a hut

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program to calculate the surface area of ​​a shack with a pitched roof. I've only been in this class for 2 weeks and I'm a bit overwhelmed. The program should ask the user via console for the values ​​and then calculate the values ​​using the definition.

I'm not asking for the entire code at all. But I don't understand how I can calculate inputs using a definition and then print them. this is my code so far:

```
import math

def floorspace(a,b):

    G = 0
    G = a*b
    
    return (G)


#main program

a = int(input("enter the length of the floor!"))
b = int(input("Enter the width of the floor!"))

print(floorspace, G)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I guess, you need to pass parameters to your function `print(floorspace(a,b), G)`

Comment: Change your last line to: `print(floorspace(a,b))`

Comment: Surface area or floor area?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import `math` as basic multiplication is already included. You also don't need to initialize a variable before you assign it so I removed the

```
G = 0
G = a*b
```

lines and replaced it with a simple

```
return a*b
```

You don't need brackets around a return statement, just a print statement.

The final two issues are that you're printing incorrectly and you used the wrong function parameters. You would need to pass in the same number of parameters that are in the function declaration (so in this case, 2). Pass in `a` and `b` from the user inputs into your `floorspace()` function and then call `print()`. The code should work now!

```
def floorspace(a,b):
    return a*b


#main program

a = int(input("enter the length of the floor!"))
b = int(input("Enter the width of the floor!"))

print(floorspace(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code `print(floorspace,G)` G is not defined you must write your it like this `print(floorspace(a,b))`